# Probabilistic inequality with two random variables

Tags: probability-theory

The problem:

> Let $\xi,\eta$ be two independent integrable r.v. such that $\mathsf P\{\xi> 0\} = 1$ and $\mathsf P\{\eta\geq 0\} = 1$ and 
>   $$
> a = \mathsf E[\xi-\eta]>0.
> $$
>   Check if 
>   $$
> \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\mathsf P\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi\geq y\} = 1
> $$
>   for any fixed $y$.

I can neither prove that the limit is $1$ nor find a counterexample, so any help is appreciated.

What I've tried so far: since $a>0$ then $p = \mathsf P\{\xi-\eta\geq a\}>0$. Then for a fixed $y$ we have:
$$
\mathsf P\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi\geq y\} \geq p\cdot \mathsf P\{a+k\xi\geq y|\xi-\eta\geq a\}
$$
but even if $\mathsf P\{a+k\xi\geq y|\xi-\eta\geq a\}\to1$ with $k\to\infty$ it woulnd't be sufficient for the original problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think independence is necessary. Since $E[\xi-\eta]>0$, $P(\eta=\infty)=0$. So, for almost every $\omega$, by *archimedean property* we can find an integer $k$ such that $(k+1)\xi(\omega)\ge \eta(\omega)+y$.

Hence $$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi\ge y\}\right)=1$$
Since the events in the union are increasing in $k$, we have $$\lim_{k\to \infty}P\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi\ge y\}=1$$

Comment: Thanks, seems to be right. Do you think it is possible to find how $\mathsf P\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi\geq y\}$ is close to $1$ for $k$ being large?

Comment: $\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi\ge y\}\uparrow \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi\ge y\}$ right? I hope I understood your doubt correctly.

Comment: nope, I meant bounds on the difference $1-\mathsf P$ as I presented in my answer below. I would appreciate if you could take a look on it and tell me if there are any mistakes or there are better bounds - though I cannot ask you to do it because your answer is cool and clear, good job ;)

Answer (score 4):

Since $\mathsf{P}\{\xi> 0\} = 1$, we have
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\left\{\xi>\frac{y+\frac{2}{\epsilon}\mathsf{E}|\xi-\eta|}{k}\right\}=1\tag{1}
$$
for any $\epsilon>0$. Furthermore, [Markov's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) implies that
$$
\mathsf{P}\left\{\xi-\eta<-\frac{2}{\epsilon}\mathsf{E}|\xi-\eta|\right\}\le\mathsf{P}\left\{|\xi-\eta|>\frac{2}{\epsilon}\mathsf{E}|\xi-\eta|\right\}\le\frac{\epsilon}{2}\tag{2}
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(x+y\ge A+B)
&\ge\mathsf{P}(x\ge A\wedge y\ge B)\\
&=\mathsf{P}(x\ge A)-\mathsf{P}(x\ge A\wedge y<B)\\
&\ge\mathsf{P}(x\ge A)-\mathsf{P}(y<B)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, given $\epsilon>0$, $(1)$ insures that there is a $k$ so that
$$
\mathsf{P}\left\{\xi>\frac{y+\frac{2}{\epsilon}\mathsf{E}|\xi-\eta|}{k}\right\}\ge1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\tag{4}
$$
then $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$ yield
$$
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi>y\}
&\ge\mathsf{P}\{k\xi>y+\frac{2}{\epsilon}\mathsf{E}|\xi-\eta|\}-\mathsf{P}\{\xi-\eta<-\frac{2}{\epsilon}\mathsf{E}|\xi-\eta|\}\\
&\ge1-\epsilon\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(5)$ tells us that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi>y\}=1
$$

Comment: cool answer, thanks a lot. The only thing I wonder about now - is that no one of us used the fact that $a = \mathsf E(\xi-\eta)>0$ and maybe bounds would be better in that case.

Comment: It is $a=\mathsf{E}|\xi-\eta|>0$ (absolute values) which is simply a way of saying that $a=\mathsf{E}|\xi-\eta|\not=0$, and it was used with Markov's Inequality.

Comment: nice point, but it can hold as well if $a<0$. Nevertheless, it seems to me now that it's not so important what is greater, $\xi$ or $\eta$ because we mostly use $k\xi$ to obtain bounds

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the answer by Ashok, I also derived bounds for the convergence which I need as well. Just for the case I put it here as an answer.

Let us take $F_\xi$ to be a c.d.f. of $\xi$. Consider
$$
1-\mathsf P\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi\geq y\} = \mathsf P\{\eta > (k+1)\xi -y\}.
$$
We have then:
$$
\mathsf P\{\eta > (k+1)\xi -y\} = \int\limits_0^\infty \mathsf P\{\eta > (k+1)x -y\}\,dF_\xi(x)$$
$$ 
= \int\limits_0^{\frac{y+\sqrt{k+1}}{k+1}} \mathsf P\{\eta > (k+1)x -y\}\,dF_\xi(x)+\int\limits_{\frac{y+\sqrt {k+1}}{k+1}}^\infty \mathsf P\{\eta > (k+1)x -y\}\,dF_\xi(x).
$$
The first term is $\displaystyle{F_\xi\left(\frac{y+\sqrt{k+1}}{k+1}\right)}$ and the second we bound by [Markov inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality):
$$
\int\limits_{\frac{y+\sqrt {k+1}}{k+1}}^\infty \mathsf P\{\eta > (k+1)x -y\}\,dF_\xi(x)\leq \mathsf E\eta\int\limits_{\frac{y+\sqrt {k+1}}{k+1}}^\infty \frac{dF_\xi(x)}{(k+1)x-y}.
$$

Since for the denominator we have: $(k+1)x-y\geq \sqrt{k+1}$ for all $x$ in the domain of integration,
$$
\int\limits_{\frac{y+\sqrt {k+1}}{k+1}}^\infty \mathsf P\{\eta > (k+1)x -y\}\,dF_\xi(x)\leq \frac{\mathsf E\eta}{\sqrt{k+1}}
$$
so
$$
\mathsf P\{\eta > (k+1)\xi -y\}\leq F_\xi\left(\frac{y+\sqrt{k+1}}{k+1}\right)+\frac{\mathsf E\eta}{\sqrt{k+1}}
$$
which in particular means that $\mathsf P\{(\xi-\eta)+k\xi\geq y\}\to 1$ with $k\to\infty$.